# How can I blur the background of an image using Capture One Pro?

Tags: photo-editing, capture-one

In Capture One Pro 8.x Is there a way to strongly blur the background of an image? I tried using an adjustment layer and the negative slider values for "clarity", "structure" and "sharpness" but that doesn't blur the background strong enough. I would like to blur it in a way as if it was out of focus (shallow depth of field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, no. All of the control you have within Capture One Pro can be summed up as emphasizing or de-emphasizing the existing sharpness in the image. That is the normal state of affairs with raw image processors. You would need to edit in an external application to actually blur the image (or selected parts of it). If you aren't using a separate image editor at the moment (Photoshop or similar) that has synthetic lens blur, there are plugins that can be used stand-alone (usually with a minimal "host" utility) such as Topaz Lens Effects or Alien Skin Bokeh that will let you give the background a believable out-of-focus blur.

Comment: Not correct as per 2016. You can have filters now apply to masks. So you can make a mask for the background and unsharpen.

Answer (score 5):

you can do a similar effect with Brush tool and reducing the Clarity in this layer.
Regards from Chile.

Comment: Could you provide the name of the software used ?

Comment: He was referring to use Capture One's builtin brush tool and then apply some negative Clarity to that layer. (though it's not a very good "blur" but better than nothing)

Answer (score 0):

Use a smart brush to select what you want to blur, then use negative dehaze. Set the shadow tone to manual and choose the background color. That works if you are shooting against a relatively uniform background color.